# Using keras.metrics.FalseNegatives() with sparsely encoded labels in TensorOverflow produces an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, metrics

Because of my specific application I would like to use the True Positive (TP), True Negative (TN), False Positive (FP) and False Negative (FP) metrics that TensorFlow natively provides. However, if I add any of these metrics, I get not so informative error about incompatible shapes.

The problem is best illustrated by short code demonstration based on the classic TensorFlow example;

```py
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train),(x_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy',
                       tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives()
                       ]
              )

model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test,y_test, return_dict=True)
```

Any ideas what is causing the problem? Have I used the metric wrong? Or am I out of luck and it simply does not support Sparse Encoding?

**UPDATE:** using tf.one_hot() to convert the y_train and y_test into "one hot" encoding and changing the loss function to categorical entropy to match, has enabled the use of the FalseNegative metric. However, this has led to meaningful slow-down of the training and testing process.